# Downgrade mySQL 8 [Ubuntu 20.04] down to mySQL 5.7 without losing data (Drupal 7)

Tags: mysql

I took the opportunity to upgrade to a wonderful Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04 sadly without researching the MySQL server upgrade effects on my Drupal 7 projects setup. I need to remain really on mySQL community server 5.7 as my data is Drupal v7.56+ and I'm not yet ready to jump upto D8 for a few months and just need to drop 5.7 in as to reconnect with my <localhost/project-name> mySQL data.

I have (post install Ubuntu 20.04) read much such as (https://www.fosstechnix.com/how-to-install-mysql-5-7-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/) but am a little perplexed.

My :`~$ apt-cache-policy mysql-server` reads as:

```
mysql-server:
  Installed: 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4
  Candidate: 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4
  Version table:
 *** 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     8.0.19-0ubuntu5 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     5.7.32-1ubuntu18.04 500
        500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic/mysql-5.7 amd64 Packages
```

How do I safely downgrade to mySQL 5.7 from mySQL 8 using CLI without losing my current SQL databases?
Cheers.

Comment: Export all your databases using `mysqldump`. Purge `MySQL` from your system. Install `MySQL` as per the linked article. Import your databases, which, according to [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/is-it-possible-to-import-db-tables-to-mysql-5-7-from-msyql-8-0-19) should give you no issues.

Comment: Thanks Jos, an option I have done before, so yeah aok. Was just hoping any other route. Cheers.

Comment: No cant do that get an error: mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) when trying to connect

Comment: I think this a mySQL DB connection error, after my 20.04 upgrade messing with my old setup and replacing SQL 5.7 with 8. I'll do some tinkering and come back here.

Comment: Jesus what a pickle!! I've downloaded the https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.7.html .DEB, what on earth do I do now???!  Well fecked up my machine, should've stayed 18.04.

Comment: You need to do `sudo dpkg -i name-of-deb-file.deb` to install it.

Comment: Reverted back to 18.04 with a fresh install. Someone flag to close, thank you.